# Pyspark returns null value for timestamp schema

Tags: pyspark

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, TimestampType, 
>>> schema = StructType([StructField('Date/Time', TimestampType(), True)]

df = spark.read.load('x/x.csv', format="csv", header="true", schema=schema)
```

df.show(10)

+---------+
|Date/Time|
+---------+
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
|     null|
+---------+

Please help.

Thanks,
Blessy

Comment: Please post some sample data

Comment: line1 "Date"                                                                                                                                     line2 "4/8/2022 0:01:00"

Comment: csv file is having a string data that is the issue. But not sure how to load data using spark.read.load statements.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your date doesn't have a proper format. Change your schema to `StringType`, or don't use schema at all, then parse those dates using `to_timestamp`

```
df.withColumn('date2', F.to_timestamp('date', 'd/M/yyyy H:mm:ss'))

+----------------+-------------------+
|            date|              date2|
+----------------+-------------------+
|4/8/2022 0:01:00|2022-08-04 00:01:00|
+----------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Is there a way we can use the timestamptype schema and get the date format corrected? Thanks again.

Comment: No if your date format is like that